# Examples of Applied Micro Paper with R (!) Code and Data in Public Repository

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, data-request, r

Can anyone suggest examples of relatively simple applied micro papers (e.g. an RCT or straightforward regression model) of possible interest to a general audience, that have their data and code, written in R, as opposed to Stata or anything else, in a public Internet repository?

That's a lot of conditions, but I'm hoping for examples that meet all of them. AER, AEJ: Applied, REStud and REStat all have nice public repositories. With the exception of REStat, which uses Dataverse, the repositories aren't searchable, so it's a pain to look through each set of files to see whether they use R or Stata. Most everyone, myself included, uses Stata, but I'd like to find some papers using R.

Answer (score 6):

You could try searching the Harvard Dataverse for `fileType:"R Data"` like this: https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataverse/harvard?q=fileType%3A%22R+Data%22

[image]

I think your use case of wanting to search for data in specific formats such as RData is a common one so I just created an issue about improving Dataverse to support this use case better: https://github.com/IQSS/dataverse/issues/2707

Comment: Thanks. I did a similar search in REStat's Dataverse archive, and found [one example](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/28521)